# How to remove alert message from NuGetGallery

Tags: nugetgallery

I have installed NuGet on my machine, but I can't disable the Yellow Alert message "This is a development environment. No data will be preserved."

I have changed in my web.config this key

```
<add key="Gallery.Environment" value="Development" />
```

to

```
<add key="Gallery.Environment" value="Production" />
```

But it is still appearring... Any idea on where to look?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Delete file Alert.md from App_data folder